# Error: Only live keys can access this method

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to take a reference of bank account token with createExternalAcccount method using stripe with node.js by using stripe test account. I get error like "Error: Only live keys can access this method."

```
stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
  'acct_**************Wu',
  {external_account: 'btok_**********************pw'},function(err,account){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(account);
  }
);
```

Comment: As you've already suggested, you're using a stripe test account, and the error is stating you can only use a live account.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a real account for real transactions, you'll need to use your live mode keys (you're currently using your test mode keys).

If you want to test bank account (ACH) transactions in test mode, you should [see this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#testing-ach).